# Sorting parent objects with multiple children

Tags: user-expectation, information-architecture, sorting

I'm working with an application for the construction industry which lets users manage and organize their daily jobs. Part of this app is a view in which you can add jobs and assign cost codes (the specific type of work) to each job. 
The cost codes are already drag-able, however there also needs to be a way to organize the jobs. In terms of technical limitations, jobs can't be draggable but they can be sortable.

So my question here is **how do I clearly show that these top-level objects are sortable?** Where should I expose that functionality? On each of the parent "Job" elements, or at the top?

Take a look at "Bridge Sample Estimate" and "Country Road 14" - these are the jobs that need to be sortable:

[image: Screenshot of a couple jobs with assigned cost codes.]

Comment: Hi Isabelle, welcome to UX.SE! Your original question read a lot like it was focused on the specific icon you should use, so [to keep it within the scope of our site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I've refocused your question to something that we are more able to help you with. If you would like to make further changes, or if I made a mistake, please feel free to [edit] your question again!

Comment: Also, I've removed the last question you had about increasing visibility of the top-level Job objects so that the answers can be focused on one question at a time. Feel free to open a new question for that if you can't find any [similar questions that might help](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+parent+child+hierarchy).

Comment: What properties of each job can you sort by?

Answer (score 1):

### Try using the top left of the table for explicitly stating the sort orders possible for both the Jobs and the Cost Codes.

You can set the sort orders for both the Jobs and the cost codes, and see both orders next to each other.

[image]

Forgive the wonky icon showing the numerical sort; I just wanted to piece something together to show the user the different sort types available.

I also put in a search box top left.